# repaint - painting and deleting immediately

Tags: java, swing, repaint, runnable

I have a project of ping pong (kind of) and it works but there is a problem in the run() function. if i draw the frame with functions i wrote to the panel(they work, i checked) it give a problem of graphics and if i use repaint(as i suupose to) it draw the frame and immediatly delete it, every solution will help(better a simple one in the level of my code):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Kit;



public class Picture extends JPanel implements MouseListener, Runnable{

    private int k = 0;
    Thread MyThread;
    private DrawPic img;
 
    private Rectangle r1, r3;

    public Picture(DrawPic img, Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect3) {
        super();
        this.setLocation(0, 85);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setSize(1280, 1024);
          
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        this.setFocusable(true);
      
        this.r1 = rect1;
    
        this.r3 = rect3;
        this.img = img;
        this.MyThread = new Thread(this);
        MyThread.start();
        this.setVisible(true);
    
    }
    
    

 
    public void paintRectangleL(Rectangle rect, Graphics g) {
        k = 3;
        
        rect.DrawRectangle(g);
        rect.FillRectangle(g);


    }
    public void paintRectangleR(Rectangle rect, Graphics g) {
        k = 1;
      
        rect.DrawRectangle(g);
        rect.FillRectangle(g);

    }
    public void paintImage(DrawPic img, Graphics g) {
        k = 2;
     
        //g.clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        img.DrawImg(g, this);
        


    }
    public void changeK(int k1){
        k = k1;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
      
        
       
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        
            Point p = r3.FindCenter();
            double dx, dy;

            dy = e.getY() - p.getY();
            r3.Move(0, dy);
              this.getGraphics().clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            this.paintRectangleL(r3, this.getGraphics());
            this.paintRectangleR(r1, this.getGraphics());
            this.paintImage(img, this.getGraphics());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        //   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
    public void animate(){
        double dx = 0, dy = 2;
        if ((this.img.getX() + 160 + this.r1.RightPoint().getX() - this.r1.LeftPoint().getX() > this.getWidth() || this.img.getX() < this.r3.RightPoint().getX() - this.r3.LeftPoint().getX())) {
                    dx = -1 * dx;
                    

                }
                if (this.img.getY() + 120> this.getHeight() || this.img.getY() < 0 ) {
                    dy = -1 * dy;
                }
                img.Move(dx, dy);
             //   this.getGraphics().clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
              //  this.paintImage(img, this.getGraphics());
              //  this.paintRectangleL(r3, this.getGraphics());
              //  this.paintRectangleR(r1, this.getGraphics());
                repaint();            
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        
        Color col;
        while (true) {
                 animate();

                try {
                    MyThread.sleep(35);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Picture.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        //   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
```

Comment: You're probably going to want to override `paintComponent()` and add all your painting there.  `paintComponent` will have a Graphics argument that you can use (instead of having to call `getGraphics()`), and will get called automatically from `repaint()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use `getGraphics()` for custom painting, as it is a temporary buffer which is recycled on next repaint. Do you painting in `paintComponent()`.

See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more information and examples. Section [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) has a good summary of `paint()` and `paintComponent()` methods. Also see [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

***EDIT:***

The logic and structure of your program does not fit Swing's painting process. You need to refactor your program so it can plug into that process and paint right stuff at right times. 
Usually, you customize component by overriding its `paintComponent()`. In that method all the painting happens. This method should be as quick as possible, avoid putting any/too much application logic in there.

You should maintain some sort of state of the painted objects, (ie coordinates, colors, etc), once the state changes issue `repaint()`. This will schedule a repaint and eventually Swing will execute `paint()` on the component which will call `paintComponent()`.

In you case, you have a timer that fires periodically. You can override `paintComponent` of the `JPanel` you use. You already have logic that does calculations of coordinates. Store these coordinates in member variables. Then, issue `repaint()`. In `paintComponent`, draw the image based on the calculated coordinates.

***EDIT:***

Another note on threads. Swing has a single threaded painting model. All UI interaction and painting is carried on Swing's *Event Dispatch Thread* (EDT). Look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more info on EDT. Note that method `animate()` is not executed on EDT. You did not show what `img.Move(dx, dy)` does, but it is probably unsafe to be executed this way. [invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) may help here to ensure the code is executed on EDT. However, in this particular case it may be easier to use [Swing timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), which ensure the actions are carried on EDT.

Comment: For example see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12336475/1048330) example that moves an image on timer pulse.

Comment: sorry for the ignorance of java, but could you give please something more clear?

Comment: +1, for linking to the Swing tutorial on custom painting. It is the most basic and has working examples that you can download and play with. If that is not clear enough then you need to ask specific questions because we are not mind readers.

Comment: @Aqua now I understand you

Comment: @mKorbel thank you! I added some details regarding threads as well.